# Is beheading non Muslim prisoners-of-war allowed in Islam?

Tags: non-muslim, jihad, war, daesh

Is it allowable for an Islamic nation to behead prisoners it captures in a war (like how ISIS has captured and beheaded an American)? Is there any Quranic or hadith justification for this?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for *seeking clarification* or providing *constructive criticism*, they are *not* to be used for argument or debate.  If you find your discussion veering away from the topic of *this particular post*, take it to [chat] (an earned privilege for any users who have acquired 20 reputation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I’m not sure about the specific hadith or Qur’anic justification but IF the prisoner has committed the crime punishable by beheading then yes, the **state** can punish the prisoner according to its law! BUT the punishment must be from the ruling state or the proper authority (courts etc. depending upon the state law), and not from any individual who takes law in his/her own hands.

That was my personal understanding of your question and the answer is what i think is the best answer... again, I am not a Muslim scholar or Molvi. It's just my personal observation. Hope it helped.

Comment: I am asking about a war prisoner who s crime is that he is from opposing \ enemy country?

Comment: So if there is an Islamic state he can be beheaded right?

Comment: Yes there are certain crimes punishable by beheading. Although only a few countries still carry out executions that way.. Saudi Arabia is one of them.

Comment: Please proof this with versus from the Quran!

Comment: As I told in the answer it's just my personal observation. If I knew the verses I would have quoted them beforehand

Comment: @Aboudi  a simple quranic search with context of war brings you :http://quran.com/8/12  [Remember] when your Lord inspired to the angels, "I am with you, so strengthen those who have believed. I will cast terror into the hearts of those who disbelieved, so strike [them] upon the necks and strike from them every fingertip."

Comment: and above is not even about punishing for crime but in a state of war like how ISIS is in war with all infidel nations.

Answer (score 2):

**بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم**

In the name of Allah the merciful the compassionate

Islamic nation should act based on Islamic teachings. There is no verse or hadith explicitly allowing beheading of war prisoners. As for historical proof, we see that the prophet never beheaded any one when he [**conquested Mecca**](http://www.al-islam.org/hayat-al-qulub-vol-2-allamah-muhammad-baqir-al-majlisi/conquest-mecca), although they were clearly idolaters (he only ordered to kill some of them who were murderers and criminals). In fact he was very kind to the slaves. He said:

> Give them of the same food of which you eat yourselves, and provide
>   them with the same kind of clothes as you put on yourselves. Do not
>   force them to do jobs which are too difficult for them. Share with
>   them their jobs and help them in the performance of them. Do not call
>   them slaves, for all men are the bondsmen of Allah, who is the real
>   Master of everyone. Call your male slaves young man and your female
>   slaves young woman **(1)**

**References**

**1-** [Men and universe](http://www.al-islam.org/man-and-universe-ayatullah-murtadha-mutahhari/chapter-21-holy-prophet#treatment-slaves) by Ayatullah [Murtadha Mutahhari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morteza_Motahhari).

Answer (score 0):

The Islamic rule is based on the "eye for an eye" concept; you can only attack those who attack you and harm those who harm you. Beheading innocent civilians is unislamic.

Comment: Where does it say like that eye for eye? Are there not many verses in Qur'an which say forgive it is better for you?

Answer (score -5):

In the Hanafi madhab it is not permissible to execute prisoners of war. But in the other three madhabs it is.

Comment: I think the OP means "beheading" not other ways of killing.

Comment: References would go a long way here...